# crontab run bad a python scraper

Tags: python, linux, cron

i've a python scraper script inside a linux vm that open google chrome and download some files creating a new folder every time.

running `/usr/bin/python3 /home/myuser/file.py` from terminal works correctly: it opens chrome, download the files a save them into a new folder.

Using crontab i scheduled like `* * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/myuser/file.py`.

unfortunately chrome not appear however i seen that the new folders, without files, was created. So i think that the script starts but it works bad.

Comment: What is the error? please show some logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> /usr/bin/python3 /home/myuser/file.py from terminal works correctly: it opens chrome.
> Using crontab ... unfortunately chrome not appear

calling via crontab there's no DISPLAY or stuff like that, try this

```
% unset DISPLAY
% /usr/bin/python3 /home/myuser/file.py
```

then instead of downloading files with a browser, consider to download them with 'curl' or 'wget'

p.s. calling your script every minute via crontab, you can easily bump into a race condition if it doesn't finish during a minute

Comment: Your response was very useful. I did not know that via crontab there's no display so i modified the script using the chrome option "--headless" in python. Now it works! thank you